# ¿Cómo saber qué `button` he clickado en AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ventana, ng-repeat

Estoy empezando con AngularJS y la verdad que me está costando.
En mi aplicación tengo un `ng-repeat` que me genera unos `h3` con un texto especifico de cada `h3`. Cambié la aplicacion para generar `button` en vez de `h3` y que al clickar me salga una ventana emergente que logré con CSS, pero cuando clicko en cualquier `button` me sale la info del primero.

¿Cómo puedo enlazar o qué puedo hacer para que cada `button` muestre su información?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: pues obteniendo el indice de los elementos, y cuando clickes en el boton ya puedes diferenciarlos

Comment: Si eso lo que con $index pero no se como puedo coger ese $index del button con el del texto que sería el mismo no? Probé con un ng-if y con un ng-show pero no se si está bien. ng-if="$index == $index lo que no se es como hacer para diferenciarlos

Comment: Hola Sara, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla y aprender cómo hacer buenas preguntas en SOes y qué es un [mcve]. Las preguntas de este tipo deben mostrar el código para poder entender mejor el escenario y encontrar problemas/soluciones

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar ngFor, pasando la lista de botones, una vez tienes la lista de botones "listaboton" con el for cada elemento boton tiene todos sus atributos name etc y aparte tiene el indice, al hacer click puedes pasar el indice del boton y asi diferenciarlos, espero con eso te ayude.

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let boton of listaboton; let i = index">
        <ion-button (click)="posicionBoton(boton.name,i)>
            {{boton.name}} = {{listaboton[i].name}}
        </ion-button>               
</ion-col>
```

algo asi

Comment: Deberías explicar por qué tu propuesta soluciona el problema.

Comment: tengo el comentario arriba, pasas una lista de botones, de los cuales tienes los datos que quieres y el indice, y en el clic pues le dices que boton as pulsado pasando le el indice, poco mas,

Comment: Un comentario no es una respuesta, es un comentario. Deberías explicar **en la respuesta** por qué tu propuesta soluciona el problema.

Comment: Respuesta no aplica, porque el OP indica que esta utilizando AngularJS, y la solucion entregada por @jesuscabrera es para Angular2+

Answer (score 0):

hola segun lo que entendi es algo asi.

---

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='miapp'>
<head>
 <title>hola</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='micontrollerApp'>

 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="main in list">
   <button ng-click="ventana(main)">{{main.title}}</button>
  </li>
 </ul>

<script>
var app = angular.module('miapp', [])
app.controller('micontrollerApp',['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.list = [
{id:'1',title:'btn1'},
{id:'2',title:'btn2'},
{id:'3',title:'btn3'}
]

$scope.ventana = function(info){
 alert('SOY LA VENTANA con el id - '+info.id);
 alert('SOY LA VENTANA con el titulo - '+info.title);
}
}])
</script>

</body>
</html>
```